# How to activate an Outlook Mail Add-In in Compose Mode?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am working on a so-called Outlook Mail Add-In (not COM, but a Mail App/web-based). To activate it in the Compose Mode in Outlook Desktop Client, I currently need to click on Apps for Office in the Ribbon, then select the corresponding Mail Add-In and then click on Start so that it finally shows in the right pane of the Compose Form.

That is not very efficient from a users point of view, if this is done several times a day.

Is there a way to start/activate such a Outlook Mail Add-In via a command, for example having a COM-based / VSTO add-in that can do the steps in one go, as described above?

Many thanks for any hints!

Comment: this question is about `outlook`, not about 'C'.  Suggest remove the `c` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook (nor VSTO) doesn't provide anything for that.

You need to install Office Apps manually. There is no API for that.